# Why is the automatically generated file descriptor starting at 3?

Tags: python, file-descriptor, temporary-files

Are the file descriptors with a lower value opened for a different process, if so which, or is this just a convention?

See the following interpreter session below, executed in Ubuntu20.04 on WSL2:

```py
Python 3.8.2 (default, Jul 16 2020, 14:00:26)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> import tempfile
>>>
>>> fd, path_3 = tempfile.mkstemp()
>>> print(fd, path_3)
3 /tmp/tmpeaqkgmmg
>>>
>>> fd, path_4 = tempfile.mkstemp()
>>> print(fd, path_4)
4 /tmp/tmp3tskrarr
>>>
>>> os.close(3)
>>> os.unlink(path_3)
>>>
>>> os.close(4)
>>> os.unlink(path_4)
>>>
>>> fd, path_3 = tempfile.mkstemp()
>>> print(fd, path_3)
3 /tmp/tmpsyqvut1r
```

From the above session is clear that when the file descriptor is not in use anymore, the `mkstemp` automatically selects the lowest number available. So, what about 0, 1 and 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0, 1 and 2 are file descriptors linked with the standard input, output and error respectively. Every process in a POSIX compliant system should have them. You can see this as a direct consequence of the "everything is a file" philosophy: input is like a file you can read from and output is like a file you can write to.

As Tryph mentioned in the comments, you may read [the wiki article on file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) for more information.

Comment: a link to a external resource which details the answer would make the answer event better IMHO (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor or http://faculty.salina.k-state.edu/tim/unix_sg/nonprogrammers/io.html for example)